# Where Function in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Basically I have so far managed to produce this:

```
sqlite> SELECT city, COUNT(bname) AS sum FROM building GROUP BY city;
city        sum       
----------  ----------
Leeds       3         
London      1         
New York    2         
Paris       1
```

However what I want to do is only print the Cities that have a sum > 1.
I have tried this:

```
sqlite> SELECT city, COUNT(bname) AS sum FROM building WHERE sum>1 GROUP BY city;
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: misuse of aggregate: COUNT()
```

Can someone explain why this isn't working, an what I shoud do instead?
Thanks

Comment: A bit nitpicking on the terminology: `where` is an *operator* not a "function"

Answer (score 5):

When you want to limit your resultset based on an aggregate function you use the HAVING clause instead of where:

```
SELECT city,
  COUNT(bname) AS sum
FROM building
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(bname) > 1;
```

There are good explanations on stackoverflow on why you can't use WHERE, but here's a short one:

Here's what happens when you do a SELECT:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY
   (This list can be bigger in some RDBMS, but this should give you an idea)

Because you are doing a GROUP BY to get your COUNT, you can't limit that on WHERE clause because it already happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use having when filtering based on the result of an aggregate function

```
SELECT city, COUNT(bname) AS sum 
FROM building 
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(bname) > 1;
```

Comment: The `having` clause should come after the `group by` clause.